# Using nextval to insert new data in table from temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, nextval

I'm having issues with the following (in PostgreSQL).

**Purpose:**

- read data from temp table `tmp`
- process this to another table `y`
- use the `nextval` from table `y` combined with data from `tmp`.

I thought this would do the job:

```
INSERT INTO y (v1, v2) VALUES (nextval(y.v1), SELECT v2 FROM tmp)
```

also tried:

```
INSERT INTO y (v1, v2) VALUES (SELECT nextval(y.v1), v2 FROM tmp)
```

can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: Do you need a single value of `v1` for all records read from tmp?

Comment: yes, this query is looped, so a single value (the next ID) is what I need here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two misconceptions/error in the code you have shown:

1. `nextval()` expects the name of a sequence, not a column name.
2. If a `select` statement is used to supply the data for an `insert` statement, you can't use `values()`

I *think* you want something like is:

```
insert into y (v1, v2) 
select nextval(...), v2 
from tmp;
```

It is unclear to me what you mean with "*use the nextval from table y*". As already mentioned nextval() operates on sequences not on tables or columns. If you mean "*take the nextval from the sequence associated with y.v1*" and `y.v1` is defined as a `serial` column you can do something like this:

```
insert into y (v1, v2) 
select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('y','v1')), v2 
from tmp;
```

But this requires `v1` to be defined as `serial`

Comment: Thanks, I will dig into this later today. Your input did make some things clear for me!